# AJAX Axios menssagem de loading JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, http, axios

Eu estou fazendo uma requisição AJAX usando a API do Github pelo axios e queria saber como eu faço para, enquanto estiver carregando as informações, ele dar um `console.log('carregando');` e criar um componente  escrito "carregando", e apos isso ele apagar as menssagens de loading.

Este é meu código atual:

```
axios.get('https:api.github.com/users/marceloh13')
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data.avatar_url)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

É só executar o `console.log` antes de fazer a requisição AJAX mesmo. E depois é só aproveitar que o axios retorna uma Promise e adicionar um `.then` no final para "cancelar" o "loader".

```
console.log('Carregando...');
axios.get('https:api.github.com/users/marceloh13')
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        console.log(response.data.avatar_url)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error);
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log("AJAX finalizado"); // sempre executa
    });
```

**Edit**: Adicionando um [exemplo funcional](https://jsfiddle.net/h892kuzg/1/).

Comment: porem mais tarde eu queria trocar esse console.log para um <h1> escrito "carregando" e apos ele carregar o <h1> some, dessa maneira n iria funcionar.

Comment: Pelo contrário. É só substituir o primeiro `console.log` por `ajaxFeedback.hidden = false;` e o `console.log` do último `then` por `ajaxFeedback.hidden = true`. No caso seria necessário que `ajaxFeedback` já esteja atribuído.

Comment: Adicionei um JSFiddle com um exemplo funcionando pra tu ter uma ideia.

Comment: Fernando, não entendi como eu faço pra criar um componente do tipo <h1> dessa maneira.

Comment: Se tu quiser criar um `<h1>` cada vez que uma requisição é começada teria que usar `document.createElement('h1')` e depois adicionar ao DOM com `appendChild` ou `insertBefore`. Porém isso não é nem pouco performático, por isso eu só mostro e escondo o elemento. Mas o ponto não é esse, com o código mostrado já dá pra se ter noção de onde colocar teus códigos para dar feedback para usuário.

Answer (score 1):

Você encontra a resposta na própria documentação do Axios. Use *Interceptors*

https://github.com/axios/axios > *Interceptors*

> You can intercept requests or responses before they are handled by then or catch.

```
// Add a request interceptor
axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
// Do something before request is sent
return config;
  }, function (error) {
// Do something with request error
return Promise.reject(error);
});

// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
// Do something with response data
return response;
}, function (error) {
// Do something with response error
return Promise.reject(error);
});
```